# What is the type of a Logger function like Logger.info?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

How do I type annotate a Logger function like Logger.info? Using reveal_type returns this:

```
Revealed type is "def (msg: builtins.object, *args: builtins.object, *, exc_info: Union[None, builtins.bool, Tuple[Type[builtins.BaseException], builtins.BaseException, Union[types.TracebackType, None]], Tuple[None, None, None], builtins.BaseException] =, stack_info: builtins.bool =, stacklevel: builtins.int =, extra: Union[typing.Mapping[builtins.str, builtins.object], None] =)"
```

There must be a more concise type for this, how do I go about finding it?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly: `Logger.info` has the type `function`? Do you want to type-hint the `info` function or the logger?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? (Yes, it matters - the right answer will depend very heavily on the use case.)

Comment: @Jan I want to type-hint the `info` function

Comment: @user2357112 It's to add type-hinting in places where a log function is passed as an argument. I don't want to replace it with logging severity as the logger might be adorned to log additional context information viz https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how precise you want/need it.

Revealing the type shows you the exact signature of the function. The most accurate annotation would be using a custom tailored callable [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) reflecting that exact function signature.

To shamelessly steal from [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/logging/__init__.pyi):

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from logging import getLogger
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Optional, Protocol, Union
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias


_SysExcInfoType: TypeAlias = Union[
    tuple[type[BaseException], BaseException, Optional[TracebackType]],
    tuple[None, None, None],
]
_ExcInfoType: TypeAlias = Union[None, bool, _SysExcInfoType, BaseException]


class LogMethod(Protocol):
    def __call__(
        self,
        msg: object,
        *args: object,
        exc_info: _ExcInfoType = None,
        stack_info: bool = False,
        stacklevel: int = 1,
        extra: Optional[Mapping[str, object]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        ...


log = getLogger(__name__)

x: LogMethod = log.info
```

This should be compatible with Python `3.8+`.

---

To contrast this with the simplest possible annotation based on [`collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable), the following of course works too.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable


log = getLogger(__name__)

y: Callable[..., None] = log.info
```

And there are options in between. Depending on what you want this for.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'd be better off with the simpler annotation based on Callable, as that would avoid compatibility issues. I was looking for the equivalent of LogMethod defined within the logging module. I guess there isn't one.

Comment: @nagul Not sure what you mean by "compatibility issues". You only need to define your Protocol once, then use it wherever you need it. As for a pre-defined `LogMethod` type alias, that would be unusual since it is a _method_ of the `Logger` class. And it is very uncommon to find type hints defined for functions in a module in general.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I meant that given an option I wouldn't want to maintain a detailed type alias in case it's misleading or incorrect in future versions of python. However, I appreciate seeing how to construct a type definition from the output.